# Need help on setting up a small network

Tags: networking, firewall, svn, samba, linux-networking

Please refer the image at

http://oi51.tinypic.com/1zd6r9h.jpg

We are about to setup a new network for our lab and following are the servers we are thinking of having

- File server (Samba)
- SVN server
- Web servers (Running Apache and Tomcat)
- Development workstations.

We have purchased a "Yamaha rtx1200" router which will work as firewall/VPN.We need to access SVN and Samba servers over the internet (via VPN).

We are thinking of hosting Samba server ,SVN server and Webservers(Apache,Tomcat)   in one physical server.

1.We need some data protection(for SVN repos and Samba)but dont want to have seperate backup servers for this.I was wondering whether a Server with RAID support enough for this task (less configuration involved)?

2.Since we access SVN through HTTP how to restrict people outside the network access SVN ? Shall we use SVN over HTTPS and block HTTPS to the outside?

Any tips and suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Never, ever, use RAID as a substitute for backups.  Accidentally delete a file, or have a crash that corrupts data, and the RAID will do you no good.  Back up!
2. Definitely serve SVN over https; no reason not to.  The mod_dav_svn module is a good way to do the SVN hosting, and preventing access from outside is easy with Apache.

To prevent access from outside, simply set something like this up for the SVN directory:

```
<Location /svn>
    # typical SVN setup:
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /path/to/repo
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
    Require valid-user

    # block outside users:
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    # Enter your internal network's subnet below:
    Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks Shane.Will using an external backup drive and a utility like "rdiff" will do it?

Comment: +1. RAID will happily allow you (and certain users) to delete every single file on your filesystem.

Comment: @umanga rdiff-backup is a good solution for small-scale backup, for sure.  Depending on how much you value the data, I'd give some thought to getting a copy off-site, even if it's just carting a drive somewhere once every few months.

Comment: +1 for RAID is not a backup. Also, if you care at all about this data, do offsite backups now. Recent events (Christchurch NZ earthquake, Japan earthquake and tsunami) have shown how easy it is for buildings to get destroyed, and if your backup is buried along with your server under a pile of rubble, it's not much use to you. Bringing your external disk into work with you every day just exposes you to risk, so have multiple disks and rotate through them so you always have the latest one offsite.